# Как исправить ошибку чтения атрибута?

Tags: python, ооп

```
class Alpha:
   def __init__(self):
      self.list = [1,2,3]

   def __getattribute__(self, name):
      print(name)
      
   def __setattr__(self, name, txt):
      print(type(txt), name)
      if(name == "list" and type(txt) == list):
         self.__dict__["list"] = []
         for k in txt:
            if(type(k) == str):
               self.__dict__["list"].append(k)
         print("успешно изменено поле, бегом проверять")
      else:
         print("Нельзя устанавливать другие поля или заменять list не списком")

A = Alpha()
A.name = 121
A.list = [1,2,"Слово1", 2, "Слово2"]
```

При выполнении данного кода возникает ошибка. Тут, как понял, `__getattribute__` улавливает изменения над элементами `__dict__` и выдает ошибку, но точно не уверен. Подскажите, как ее исправить?

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки.

Comment: у вас `__getattribute__` всегда возвращает `None`. Поэтому при изменении `__dict__` происходит ошибка.  Добавьте в конце метода `__getattribute__` возврат значения базовой реализации метода `return super().__getattribute__(item)`

Comment: @godva почему бы вам не оформить свой комментарий как ответ?

Answer (score 4):

У вас метод `__getattribute__` всегда возвращает значение `None`. Поэтому при чтении любого атрибута объекта, всегда возвращается `None`, что приводит к ошибке изменения `__dict__`. Чтобы это исправить можно добавить вызов базовой реализации метода `__getattribute__` (методы `__init__` и `__setattr__` остаются без изменений - и поэтому не добавил в пример):

```py
class Alpha:

  def __getattribute__(self, name):
    print(name)
    return super().__getattribute__(name)
```